# How to constuct the HamerlyKmeans object for mlpack's kmeans

Tags: c++, templates, mlpack

I'm new to mlpack and using 3.3.1. I want to do some KMeans clustering. I can use the naiveKMeans class just fine, but I want to use another method, for example the HamelyKMeans class.

From the manual, it seems I need to construct my own local object of that class to pass it on instead of NaiveKMeans in this line of code:

```
  KMeans<mlpack::metric::EuclideanDistance, kmeans::SampleInitialization,
    kmeans::MaxVarianceNewCluster, kmeans::NaiveKMeans, arma::mat> km =KMeans(0);
```

But when I try to construct it as follows, I get a compiler error:

```
// for StackOverflow
#include <mlpack/prereqs.hpp>
#include <mlpack/core.hpp>
#include <mlpack/core/util/cli.hpp>
#include <mlpack/methods/kmeans/kmeans.hpp>
#include <mlpack/methods/kmeans/allow_empty_clusters.hpp>
#include <mlpack/methods/kmeans/kill_empty_clusters.hpp>
#include <mlpack/methods/kmeans/refined_start.hpp>
#include <mlpack/methods/kmeans/elkan_kmeans.hpp>
#include <mlpack/methods/kmeans/hamerly_kmeans.hpp>
#include <mlpack/methods/kmeans/pelleg_moore_kmeans.hpp>
#include <mlpack/methods/kmeans/dual_tree_kmeans.hpp>
using namespace mlpack;
using namespace mlpack::kmeans;
using namespace mlpack::metric;
using namespace mlpack::util;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  arma::mat in_data(10,10);
  for ( int i=0; i < 10; i++ ) {

    for ( int j=0; j < 10; j++ ) {
        in_data(j,i)=i+j;
    }
  }
  kmeans::HamerlyKMeans< metric::EuclideanDistance, arma::mat> 
ek = kmeans::HamerlyKMeans(in_data,EuclideanDistance());
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                

// HamerlyKMeans to be used instead of NaiveKMeans below


  KMeans<mlpack::metric::EuclideanDistance, kmeans::SampleInitialization,
    kmeans::MaxVarianceNewCluster, kmeans::NaiveKMeans, arma::mat> km =KMeans(0);

  arma::Row<size_t> assignments; // Cluster assignments.
  arma::mat centroids; // Cluster centroids.

  km.Cluster(in_data,5,assignments, centroids); // 5 clusters.   

}
```

The compiler error messages are:

error: no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'HamerlyKMeans'
[build]   kmeans::HamerlyKMeans< metric::EuclideanDistance, arma::mat> ek = kmeans::HamerlyKMeans(in_data,EuclideanDistance());
[build]                                                                     ^

[build] /usr/include/mlpack/methods/kmeans/hamerly_kmeans.hpp:26:3: note: candidate function [with MetricType = mlpack::metric::LMetric<2, true>, MatType = arma::Mat] not viable: expects an l-value for 2nd argument

[build]   HamerlyKMeans(const MatType& dataset, MetricType& metric);
[build]   ^
[build] /usr/include/mlpack/methods/kmeans/hamerly_kmeans.hpp:19:7: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
[build] class HamerlyKMeans
[build]       ^

But when I look in hamerly_kmeans.hpp, I see:

```
template<typename MetricType, typename MatType>
class HamerlyKMeans
{
 public:
  /**
   * Construct the HamerlyKMeans object, which must store several sets of
   * bounds.
   */
  HamerlyKMeans(const MatType& dataset, MetricType& metric);
```

I've quite fluxomed. I don't understand templates for classes at all well. Ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured this out. I changed the construction of the HamerlyKMeans class to this

```
  metric::EuclideanDistance euclid_distance;  

  kmeans::HamerlyKMeans< metric::EuclideanDistance, arma::mat> ek = 
    kmeans::HamerlyKMeans(in_data,euclid_distance);
```

The best I understand this is that the compiler told me that the second argument told me that the metric::EuclidDistance() does not construct a l-value ( I think of that as a variable but the above change creates the variable euclid_distance which is an l-value. The above change compiled and links just fine.